# Регулярные выражения Java - предварительный просмотр

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть некое регулярное выражение

> (regex)

Нужно проверить, чтобы перед ним был пробел, либо это было начало строки. Для этого используем следующее выражение:

> (?<=\s|^)(regex)

Однако такая запись работает не корректно. Корректно отрабатывает так:

> ((?<=\s|^))(regex)

Для предварительного просмотра конца строки на наличие точки, пробела или окончания строки выражение без дополнительных скобок отрабатывает корректно

> (regex)(?=\s|.|$)

В чем разница, почему необходимы еще одни скобки для предварительного просмотра вперед?

ПРИМЕР КОДА:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String REGEX_DATE_FORMAT = "(?<=\\s|^)(\\d{1,2})([-./])(\\d{1,2})(\\3)(\\d{4}|\\d{2})(?=\\s|\\.|$)";
    String line = "After shopping 15.09.10";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX_DATE_FORMAT);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    int startIndex = 0;
    if (matcher.find(startIndex)) {
        System.out.println(true);
    }
}
```

Ничего не выведет, с дополнительными кавычками вокруг первого блока выведет true

Comment: *В чем разница, почему необходимы еще одни скобки для предварительного просмотра вперед?* - А они и не нужны. Поделитесь кодом, который не работает. Кстати, и скобки вокруг `(regex)` не нужны.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew добавил пример кода

Comment: Вы ссылаетесь на значение подмаски №3, а надо на вторую. Замените `\\3` на `\\2`. См. [демо](https://ideone.com/4mZGKg).

Comment: Т.е. блок предварительного просмотра сам по себе не является блоком, хоть и тело его заключено в круглые скобки. А если такой блок поместить в круглые скобки, то с этого момента он будет распознаваться как блок. Спасибо вам огромное, теперь вроде бы разобрался с блоками предварительного просмотра.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разделитель захватывается второй подмаской, `([-./])`, однако в регулярном выражении использована обратная ссылка на третью группу (вторая `(\\d{1,2})`). По-видимому, вы решили, что скобки блока предварительного просмотра являются *захватыващими*, но это не так. Они не создают захватываемую группу/подмаску.

Используйте

```
final String REGEX_DATE_FORMAT = "(?<=\\s|^)(\\d{1,2})([-./])(\\d{1,2})(\\2)(\\d{4}|\\d{2})(?=\\s|\\.|$)";
```

Или лучше

```
final String REGEX_DATE_FORMAT = "(?<!\\S)(\\d{1,2})([-./])(\\d{1,2})(\\2)(\\d{2}(?:\\d{2})?)(?![\\s.])";
```

См. демо онлайн:

```
final String REGEX_DATE_FORMAT = "(?<!\\S)(\\d{1,2})([-./])(\\d{1,2})(\\2)(\\d{2}(?:\\d{2})?)(?![^\\s.])";
String line = "After shopping 15.09.10";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX_DATE_FORMAT);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
int startIndex = 0;
if (matcher.find(startIndex)) {
    System.out.println(true);
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Результат:

```
true
15.09.10
```

Шаблон `(?<=\\s|^)` даёт тот же результат, что `(?<!\S)`, а `(?=\\s|\\.|$)` — `(?![^\\s.])`, только быстрее, так как мы избавляемся от оператора `|`. Вместо "подтверди наличие знака X, Y либо начало/конец строки", лучше потребовать "подтверди отсутствие знака, отличного от X или Y".

Comment: "подтверди отсутствие знака, отличного от X или Y" лучше только тогда, когда в противном случае присутствовала бы операция | , или во всех случаях? Если во всех случаях, с чем это связано? И как так любопытно получается, что подтверди отсутствие не пробельного символа фактически не является тем же самым, что и подтверди наличие пробельного символа, так как, как минимум, включает в себя проверку на начало/конец строки

Comment: Я пропустил `^` в `(?![\\s.])`, надо как в коде, `(?![^\\s.])`. `(?<!\S)` не равно `(?<=\s)`, так как `(?<=\s)` требует пробельного символа перед текущей позицией, а `(?<!\S)` проверяет, есть ли непробельный символ перед текущей позицией, и "отменяет" совпадение, если он там есть. Если нет этого непробельного символа, совпадение считается валидным. Вот и вся разница.

Comment: Благодарю за столь развернутое и понятное объяснение!